# Can a (Python) Script permanently Edit my system Path variable?

Tags: python, shell, command-line, terminal, path

I'm trying to make a script that's going to do some stuff via command line. Its usage should look somewhat like this:

```
C:\users\me> appname startprocess
```

but if I'm trying to release this, I need it to be really handy for everyone to use and that needs the PATH variable to be set to my script's location.

**I want my script to handle this task by itself.** Can *my script* edit my PATH variable **permanently**? If so, how?

Most questions on this topic are mostly about how to set the path variable for python scripts instead of writing script that could do that by itself.

Comment: You have that backwards; to get the script to edit the path you'd first have to run the script, which means *knowing where it is*. I'd suggest reading up on `setup.py` and how to let people `pip install` your package with a script included. For example: https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html.

Comment: I believe there are OS-specific ways of doing it (from a Python script).

Comment: @Jitin : Your question is not clear to me. You want `appname` to change the PATH of the caller? This is possible only if `appname` runs in the same process as the caller. For instance, if `appname` is POSIX shell (which I assume from your usage of the _shell_ tag), the user needs to invoke it as `. /path/to/appname startprocess` to ensure that this is run inside the invoker's process.

Comment: its more **like** I'm trying to Install the app.
and I want it to be accessible from my shell.
So I need my python script to permanently edit my system PATH so that I could call my script any time

Answer (score 2):

For adding the current working directory to the PATH, you can use this piece of code:

```
import os
import sys
pwd = os.getcwd()
sys.path.append(pwd)
```

And for running a shell script, use this:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run('Your Command', shell = True)
```

If you want to check the output of the command:

```
stdout = subprocess.check_output('Your Command', shell = True)
print(stdout.decode())
```

Comment: But isn't that only a temporary fix, the Path variable doesn't actually change does it ?
I need a permanent change made to the Path Variable.

Comment: any more insight on that @BugHunter ?